# Asp.Net WebPages website - How to add WebApi controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webpages

I am building my site using Asp.Net Webpages 2 and Razor (C#).

I tried to insert WebApi controller and all I get is 404. Controller is a default one.

I even tried adding

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and I still get 404.

What else is there to do ?

Comment: I did it.

In Global.asax you need to add

    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>


And in Application_Start 

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
     ); 

Now it is working like it should.

It did not work before because I tried the same code in Global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 3):

I did it. In Global.asax you need to add

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
```

And in Application_Start

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

Now it is working like it should. It did not work before because I tried the same code in Global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to use _AppStart.cshtml instead of Global.asax.

```
@using System.Web.Http
@{
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

}
```

I've used this for simple cases to get information, but am not sure if it works completely.